# SQL after the JOIN remove duplicate rows

Tags: sql, select, join, duplicates, db2

I have table T1

```
ID   STATUS
1    NEW
2    CLOSED
3    NEW
```

I have table T2

```
ID   OWNER 
1    A
1    B
1    C
1    A
1    B
2    A
2    B
2    A
3    A
```

I want to join T1 and T2 and to have multiple rows for every different ID and for every different OWNER. If OWNER is repeated multiple times in T2 that should be ignored and that duplicates should be removed.

So the final desired result should be:

```
ID  STATUS  OWNER
1   NEW     A
1   NEW     B
1   NEW     C
2   CLOSED  A
2   CLOSED  B
3   NEW     A
```

So you can see that duplicates (same owner for same ID multiple times) should be removed. I just need to have output as list of IDs and every different OWNER for that ID but it is not important how many times he was responsible in T2 table. I need to make somehow distinction.

If I do the query like this I am not getting distinct values per ID and OWNER but I am also having duplicates in this case.

```
    select t1.id,t1.status,t2.owner 
    FROM  t1
    join t2 
    on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select T1.ID, T1.STATUS, t.OWNER from T1
inner join(
    select ID, OWNER from T2 group by ID, OWNER
) t
on T1.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: thank you this works!!! I marked it as an answer. Just a short question. If I need to filter T2 where should I add additional sql statments: within the T braces or at the end of your query???  For additional filtering of T1 I suppose I am adding it at the end of the query but for T2 I have doubts??? Thanks

Comment: If that filter belongs to only T2 table, then you can add this statement to subquery. (within the T braces).

Comment: Having another set of select statement inside inner join with group by desire fields makes query excution time short and faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use distinct keyward in ur query to get desired result.

```
select distinct  t1.id,t1.status,t2.owner 
    FROM  t1
    join t2 
    on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

All in all, fairly cakey.

```
create table #T1 ([ID] int, [Status] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES
(1, 'NEW'),
(2, 'CLOSED'),
(3, 'NEW')

create table #T2 ([ID] int, [Owner] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(1, 'C'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(2, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'A')

SELECT DISTINCT
 T.[ID],
 T.[Status],
 U.[Owner]
    FROM #T1 T
JOIN #T2 U ON T.[ID] = U.[ID]
```

I performed the work in SQL Server within SSMS, but pretty much any SQL-compatible engine should cover the job without issue.

Apologies, I thought there might be a unique row-reduction lesson to be learned within the example, but then it was just DISTINCT that did all the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
with T2b as (
  select * from (
    select t2.*, rownumber() over(partition by t2.ID, t2.OWNER ) rang
    from t2
  ) tmp 
  where rang=1
)
select t1.*, T2b.OWNER 
from t1 inner join T2b on t1.id=T2b.id
```